# VBA - Upload data from Excel to Access without Access installed

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA but am trying to upload data from an Excel Workbook to an Access database table from a computer that does not have Access installed. I have searched for a solution online but haven't found anything yet that I can get to work with my code.

The error code I am getting is...429 cannot create activex component

I have some VBA code set up in the Excel workbook which calls a Sub in Access [which works on a machine which has Access installed] but I don't know what the correct code should be if the machine doesn't have Access installed.

```
Sub Upload_SiteObsData_Excel_To_Access(Database_Path)

Database_Path = "\\Path\db1.mdb"

Dim acApp As Object
Dim db As Object

Set acApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("\\Path\db1.mdb")

Set db = acApp
acApp.Run "Upload_SiteObsData_to_Access"
acApp.Quit
Set acApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The procedure in Access is as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim Excel_Path As String
Dim Excel_Range As String
Dim UserNameOffice As String

Dim Excel_File_TechForm As String
Sub SetUp_Variables()

UserNameOffice = CreateObject("wscript.network").UserName

Excel_Path = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & UserNameOffice & "\Desktop\"
Excel_Range = "MyData"

Excel_File_TechForm = "SiteObsForm_v0.2.xls"

End Sub

Sub Upload_SiteObsData_to_Access()

SetUp_Variables
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "TBL_SiteObsData",   Excel_Path & Excel_File_TechForm, True

End Sub
```

I would be extremely grateful for any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: you dont have to open access to access the db. you can run any other compatible tool to open the db. Have a read on [ADODB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189885(v=office.10).aspx) and different [sql strings](http://connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: @user2338876  Yoy may have a look at Acess Runtime

Answer (score 1):

I was just fooling around with some Excel VBA code and the following seemed to work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Upload_Excel_to_Access()
Dim con As Object  '' ADODB.Connection
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  '' New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
con.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO TBL_SiteObsData " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Public\Book1.xlsm].[Sheet1$]"
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gord, Looks good. I notice you are using Office 2010...we are still running Office 2003. Do you know what the syntax should be for 2003 and I can give it a try. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'l have to find another way round this issue, without access installed, Excel cannot create the `"Access.Application"` object, it just flat-out doesn't know what access is.

Can you pull the data from Access instead?

Comment: Hi, It's purpose is to upload form data from several users located in different geographical areas [but connected to the same network] to master database. Installing Access on each computer is an added expense we were trying to avoid.

Comment: Is someone running the access application, or is it just a datastore?

Comment: Access is just the datastore

Answer (score 0):

I've done this the first time I connected Excel to Access via VBA, and I know for sure it works using the code that  [Gord Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson)  provided. Establishing an ADODB connection and executing an append query.