# Referencing Office 2013 Object Libraries From a 2003 Application

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, dll, reference

I have recently moved to Windows 7. This has involved moving to Office 2013 for all application except MS Access: Access has stayed as 2003.

The Access application works fine but I can't get any code to work which involves a reference to other Office applications unless I use late binding. This would inolve re-writing a substantial amount of code across many applications, and must be avoided at all costs.

I'm hoping that I can manually add the reference to Access' Object Library, but I don't know its physical location on my computer. Can anyone help with this? Hopefully there'll be no compatability issues with using a newer reference on an older application...?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I've since located the Reference (Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library) and ticked the box appropriately in the References Menu. I get the error message "Error in loading DLL" when I try to use some code, though. This is an incompatability between versions?

Further Edit:

I can get Word 13 to work with Access 03, but this seems to be because the Word Object Library is in an OLB file compared to Excel's EXE?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019235 might help

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm not in a position to run downloaded files or change the registry. Can you offer any further advice?

Comment: btw, why do you need to reference the Access application? can you not simply modify your code to use Access as a data store and simply run SQL commands on it? Have a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316502/vba-upload-data-from-excel-to-access-without-access-installed). It might help, since it uses Access files without even having Access installed, so it should definitely work in your case

Comment: I'm not actually using Access for its tables - my data is stored in XML files. I originally used Access as the front-end due to having better Form Controls and Events. Worst case scenario, I can re-code it into Excel 2013. I won't loose any data since I can still used MSXML